# API to query multistage heating

Tags: nest-device-access

I have a multistage furnace. Is there an API to query which stage the thermostat is calling for?

The [ThermostatHvac](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/thermostat-hvac) API only provides "OFF", "HEATING", "COOLING" but doesn't provide any more detail.

Comment: The docs you refer to also describe a THERMOSTAT device type with ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint which is the current target temperature. Does your furnace have this API and would it help?

Comment: Yes, I am able to read this value.

According to this doc: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9235693

"If your system’s first stage of heating or cooling won’t reach your desired temperature in a reasonable amount of time, your Nest thermostat will turn on additional stages of heating or cooling to ensure that you’re kept comfortable."

I want to know when the thermostat is calling for additional stages. Just knowing the set point doesn't tell me this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no APIs currently available that you can access the multi stage heating/cooling nest devices perform. You can only access the mode nest thermostat is operating in (HEAT, COOL, ON/OFF, ECO) and temperature set point currently activated.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! Please pass along my request for such a feature to be implemented in the future.